# Struggling to release my c++ project as a single executable from Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse, executable, packaging

I am working on a project in c++ and i am planning to make work with a single click not to make the users to install all the libraries . I have already asked this question but i got the answer to use the --static flag in GCC i am not sure i am using eclipse IDE and how to make it  work any advice would be appreciative

Comment: First i am  planning for linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would use an external make file and compile your application with the static gcc flag. The problem when compiling your libraries as static is that you end up with a big executable file. This is acceptable for small applications that don't use too many libraries.
I'm using CMake and I think the learning curve is quite fast, comparing to using make tools directly.

Comment: can u give me some tutorials or useful links